# Can not log on to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login

My Windows has a problem and I cannot log on to Windows.After "Please wait.." in startup windows,monitor goes off and I can not insert username or password to login!

But in safe mode there is no problem.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Monitor going off is usually resolution issue ,when you log into your system in safe mode set monitor resolution to minimum allowed and then reboot. If you are able to login to the system after this , find out what is the maximum resolution the monitor can support and set the resolution to that value.

Comment: No,i think welcome screen has error or corrupted.

Comment: Does the monitor go into standby? If so it is most likely your resolution as Shark says.